# Is it worth it to test reusable react components/hooks?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I know for testing especially react there aren't "perfect ways", and I've met with many scenarios. What I've learnt, and seen most of the time is "test behaviour, not the implementation" i.e. instead of testing for example what the values are in redux, test what the user sees. Makes sense. However, if it's the case, testing how an `Input` component should behave feels unnecessary, because it will be tested anyways when testing `Form`. But `Form` will be tested for specific cases for example on a `Login`, or `Register` page, so testing `Form` makes no sense either.

The question is is it worth the time to test reusable components/hooks if they will be tested in every case they are used, or there are tradeoffs?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of testing a single "unit" of code. If you've not tested units of code then how can you reliably test anything composed from those units and confidently say it is correct? Testing inputs via a form isn't unit testing and borders on integration testing, i.e. how units work, or *integrate*, together. Whether it's worth it or not, well, that is subjective, so I'm voting to close as opinionated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is value in testing each component in isolation. In your example, tests for `Input` will show us immediately when the problem is with its code rather than how the `Form` is using it. Tests for `Form` should test its own behavior and tests for `Input` should likewise test its individual behavior. You shouldn't write tests at the `Form` level that cover all the use cases for `Input`. Instead `Form` tests should be looking at use cases of `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid testing the child components features when testing parent components.

Enzyme's shallow rendering ensures that https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html

Comment: Being rendered !== Being tested.

Comment: @DrewReese if child component is not rendered, the dev will not be able to test child component behavior, keeping testing focused on the component being tested

Comment: Sure, but try that with the testing paradigm OP is alluding to, i.e. how react-testing-library works, and you'll find it doesn't test implementation details like enzyme does. My point was that even if you use `mount` in enzyme and the component tree is rendered, it doesn't necessarily mean children components were "tested". I get what you are trying to say, but your premise is skewed.